# Angular2 http synchronous

Tags: angular

Please help me make an example about http with synchronous in Angular2?

I tried as below:
In component:

```
getAllAddress(){
    this.addressService.getAllAddress().then(
            result => {
                this.data = result.list;
                this.onChangeTable(this.config, null);
                console.log('FIRST');
            }
        );
    console.log('LAST');
}
```

In service:

```
public getAllAddress(){
    return this.__http.get('LOCATION')
    .map((res) => {
        return res.json()
    })
    .toPromise();
}
```

But the console show log is 'LAST' before 'FIRST'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create your own implementations `Connection` and `ConnectionBackend` class and inject it while bootstrapping your app. See sample code below

```
export class XHRSynchronousConnection implements Connection    
 {

 }

export class XHRSynchronousConnectionBackend implements ConnectionBackend
{
}
```

You can bootstrap it as follows

```
bootstrap([provide(ConnectionBackend, {useClass:XHRSynchronousBackend}),
provide(Connection,{useClass:XHRSynchronousConnection}];
```

You can see the rest of the code in [actual source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.0/modules/angular2/src/http/backends/xhr_backend.ts).

Comment: no, please, no, don't do this. this is a terrible idea for any application running in the browser, as it will literally freeze the application while the request is in flight. See the MDN docs that mention this being a bad idea. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest